# Can vs Could modals

Tags: grammar, word-choice, phrase-choice, sentence-choice

> Kindly send us the catalogue of your products so that we could check
> if it meets our requirements.

Should we use "**Could**" or "**Can**" here? What would it be different in meaning with "**Can**"?

Comment: There is no modal remoteness meaning in the sentence, nor is it part of a conditional construction, so the present tense form "can" is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You use **could** rather than **can** in several situations:

When you are talking about something that happened in the past

> We used to leave the window open so that the cat **could** come in

When you are reporting what somebody said

> He said "I can come" -*direct speech*
> He said that he **could** come - *reported speech*

When you are talking about a hypothetical situation

> If I were rich, I **could** buy you a car

When being polite:

> **Could** you please bring me a glass of water

None of these situations apply to the sentence that you quoted, so you should use **can**.